# Remove Subview from Superview

Tags: ios, uiview, subview, superview

I am really stuck in this issue for quite a long time

I am trying to add a `UIControl` (which is a `UIView` in the end) to a `UITableViewCell` that i have subclasses in my own class (i made a custom cell)

on swipe, i create my `UIControl` class and add it to myself (the cell), so far so good. Here is the code

```
[self addSubview:_statusView];
```

However, i am adding a target action to my `UIControl` in the custom cell, so that the cell can handle when the `UIControl` says that he has recognized a touchDownEvent.

```
[self.statusView addTarget:self action:@selector(resetAll:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

And here is what i want to do in the action, I want to remove that `UIControl` from `self.subviews` (the cell's subviews), so i set the action method to be like this

```
- (void)resetAll:(id)sender
{
for (UIView *view in self.subviews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[StatusView class]]) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
}
```

Can someone point out whats wrong in this code? because i can't really figure out why the view that gets added to the cell does't get removed. It seem to me the the subviews property doesn't ever contain my `UIControl` that i add.

Comment: is your resetAll: selector getting called

Comment: Why not just call `[sender removeFromSuperview]`?

Comment: `resetALL:` gets called, indeed.
`sender` is the event? its not the `UIView` that i want to remove.

Comment: `-(void)resetAll:(UIView *)sender { [sender removeFromSuperview]; }`.

Comment: Why on earth did i get -1 reputation on this question? this website is kind of retarded sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITableViewCell` internally does some manipulations with its view hierarchy. You should add subviews not to the cell itself, but to its `contentView`, as stated in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> If you want to go beyond the predefined styles, you can add subviews
>   to the contentView property of the cell.

So you have to replace

```
[self addSubview:_statusView];
```

with

```
[self.contentView addSubview:_statusView];
```

And then iterate on subviews of the `contentView`:

```
for (UIView *view in self.contentView.subviews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[StatusView class]]) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Comment: Simplest solution I've found and much easier than subclassing. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)resetAll:(id)sender
{
for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[StatusView class]]) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
}
```

or

```
- (void)resetAll:(id)sender
{
[sender removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: The first solution won't work as resetAll: method is called on `UITableViewCell` and it doesn't have the `view` property

Comment: What do you mean when you say `self.view.subviews`? self is already the cell which is a UIView.

Comment: its worked for me. Thanks!for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[StatusView class]]) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}